# Call method of a class inside of another C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, methods

I'm trying to set a value for the variable myVar (located inside the myClass1) from  myClass2 (as an intermediate class). However I get a compile error.
Here is my attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass1{

    int myVar = 5;
    public:
        myClass1();

        myClass1(int x){ myVar = x; }

        int getmyVar(){ return myVar; }
        void setmyVar(int y){ myVar = y; }


};

class myClass2{

    int myScore = 10;
    myClass1 class1;
public:
    myClass2();

    myClass2(int x){ myScore = x; }

    int getmyScore(){ return myScore; }
    void setmyScore(int y){ myScore = y; }
    myClass1 getmyClass1(){ return class1; }


};

int main(){

    myClass2 class2;
    class2.getmyClass1().setmyVar(40);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall myClass2::myClass2(void)" (??0myClass2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\VB\Test2\Test2\Main.obj Test2
```

Comment: Change the method definition to myClass1& getmyClass1(){...}

Comment: btw once you return a reference from `getmyClass1` it will become rather pointless to make the `class1` member `private`. Instead of using a method to return a (non-const) reference you can make it public as well

Comment: @BoBTFish I get this error: "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall myClass2::myClass2(void)" (??0myClass2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\VB\Test2\Test2\Main.obj Test2
"

Comment: You forgot to define the default constructors. You will encounter the same error if you remove the line that you assumed to be the problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Do I need to add them? I've used a myClass1(); and myClass2(); as constructor to be able to create them, their attributes have default values.

Comment: Those are declarations, not definitions. A function body that doesn't do anything looks like `{}`, not like `;`.

Answer (score -2):

See changes marked `HERE`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass1{

    int myVar = 5;
    public:
    myClass1() {} // HERE

        myClass1(int x){ myVar = x; }

        int getmyVar(){ return myVar; }
        void setmyVar(int y){ myVar = y; }


};

class myClass2{

    int myScore = 10;
    myClass1 class1;
public:
    myClass2() {} // HERE

    myClass2(int x){ myScore = x; }

    int getmyScore(){ return myScore; }
    void setmyScore(int y){ myScore = y; }
    myClass1& getmyClass1(){ return class1; }  // HERE


};

int main(){

    myClass2 class2;
    class2.getmyClass1().setmyVar(40);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I guess the main problem was I forgot to add {} after myClass2() and after myClass1()  right?

Comment: The problem is that these functions are **declared** but not **defined**. Basically, you say "this function should exist", but it actually does not! Another solution would be to make them have **default** definitions: `myClass1() = default;`

Comment: I suspect your answer is getting downvotes because you don't actually explain the problem, or the reason your fix works. A good answer would help the asker understand, not just give something to copy/paste. That said, it is bad manners to drive-by downvote!

Comment: other than no explanation, messed up intendation and pretending to be encapsulated when it is not, I dont understand the downvotes ;)

Comment: I have a question about that. myClass1() and myClass2() is the contructor, if I don't define them, would that mean, that the compiler takes the standardt contructor? Or does class1 and class2 does not exist?

Comment: @Ahrtaler a declaration is like a promise to the compiler that you will provide the definition, the exception is to delcare it as `= default` in which case the compiler will still provide the definition

Comment: @user463035818 My compiler don't throw an error if I create a consturctor without an definition. Checked that a seccond ago. But I didn't checked, what happen if I call this consturctor. I think a runtimeexception would be the result. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: @Ahrtaler if you dont call it, there is no problem, definition and declaration can be in different places. If you call it you get a linker error (the one you got in your example above, dont really understand why you think you need to test again ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Oh I hadn't seen that link error. Yes that makes sense.